# Error: 'viewport' is already declared in the upper scope

Tags: reactjs

I am working on React-Map-GL and I am super new on it. I've added this code to my react-app but getting an error like this:

Line 28:  'viewport' is already declared in the upper scope

It uses: "eslint-config-airbnb"

Thank you in advance

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactMapGL from 'react-map-gl'



const REACT_APP_MAPBOX_TOKEN =
  'XXXMAPBOXAPIXXX'

class Map extends React.Component {
  state = {
    viewport: {
      width: 400,
      height: 400,
      latitude: 37.7577,
      longitude: -122.4376,
      zoom: 8,
    },
  }

  render() {
    const { viewport } = this.state
    return (
      <ReactMapGL
        {...viewport}
        mapboxApiAccessToken={REACT_APP_MAPBOX_TOKEN}
        onViewportChange={viewport => this.setState({ viewport })}
      />
    )
  }
}
export default Map
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `render` method, you're destructuring `viewport` from `this.state`, and then call an inner variable in `onViewportChange` with the same name. You can't use the same name for 2 variables, and that's why you're getting an error.

A proper way to write this would be -

```
render() {
  const { viewport } = this.state
   return (
    <ReactMapGL
      {...viewport}
      mapboxApiAccessToken={REACT_APP_MAPBOX_TOKEN}
      onViewportChange={newViewport => this.setState({ viewport: newViewport })}
    />
  )
}
```